# scikit learn digits dataset

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

```
In [39]: from sklearn import datasets

In [40]: data = datasets.load_digits()

In [42]: data.images
Out[42]: 
array([[[  0.,   0.,   5., ...,   1.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,  13., ...,  15.,   5.,   0.],
        [  0.,   3.,  15., ...,  11.,   8.,   0.],
        ..., 
        [  0.,   4.,  11., ...,  12.,   7.,   0.],
        [  0.,   2.,  14., ...,  12.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   6., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   5.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   9.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   3., ...,   6.,   0.,   0.],
        ..., 
        [  0.,   0.,   1., ...,   6.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   1., ...,   6.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  10.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  12.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   3., ...,  14.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   8., ...,  16.,   0.,   0.],
        ..., 
        [  0.,   9.,  16., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   3.,  13., ...,  11.,   5.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  16.,   9.,   0.]],

       ..., 
       [[  0.,   0.,   1., ...,   1.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,  13., ...,   2.,   1.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,  16., ...,  16.,   5.,   0.],
        ..., 
        [  0.,   0.,  16., ...,  15.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,  15., ...,  16.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   2., ...,   6.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   2., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,  14., ...,  15.,   1.,   0.],
        [  0.,   4.,  16., ...,  16.,   7.,   0.],
        ..., 
        [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  16.,   2.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   4., ...,  16.,   2.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   5., ...,  12.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,  10., ...,   1.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   2.,  16., ...,   1.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,  15., ...,  15.,   0.,   0.],
        ..., 
        [  0.,   4.,  16., ...,  16.,   6.,   0.],
        [  0.,   8.,  16., ...,  16.,   8.,   0.],
        [  0.,   1.,   8., ...,  12.,   1.,   0.]]])
```

Now suppose if we are given individual images as numpy arrays and we have to concatenate them as a single numpy array (basically doing the reverse of the code above), how can we proceed?

I tried something with np.dstack() but failed.

Comment: Each row in the array is just a flat list of the gray values of the pixels. Similar question on their ML: http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/31312358/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `vstack()` and `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
a = []

for i in range(5):
    a.append(np.random.randint(0, 255, (8, 8)))

np.vstack(a).reshape(len(a), -1)
```